# How can I paste my folder structure in my MT4 into a folder structure in Tradingview

Tags: mql4, pine-script

How can I paste my folder structure in my MT4 into a folder structure in Tradingview. I even try upgrading to pro to see if I can find a way to do it and I haven't spot it. Like for example I would like to just paste my indicators and templates folders just like in other MT4 of brokers.

Comment: Is your question about MT4? It seems you should add TradingView tags not MQL4.

Comment: I only mention MT4 because some of my file's code is in the MQL4 programming language, but the main issue that I am having is that unlike for the MT4 application of brokers that I can easily copy/paste the files from my flash drive and folder structure of my programs calling other files; In Tradingview I'm not finding a user friendly way to do this. If someone can direct me on how do do this it will be immensely appreciated Thank you!

Comment: MQL4 is based on C++, PineScript seems to have the other origin, probably python. They are two different languages so you will have to rewrite all you need into PS. For operations with TV, you should add tags `pine-script` or/and `tradingview-api`

Comment: Thank you Daniel I was just hoping I didn't need to rewrite everything sadly. Another question relating to this how would I incorporate a .tpl file into the charts?

Comment: I cannot help with that because I never used pine-script, only MQL4/5

Answer (score 0):

You can't. TradingView does not support importing code from other platforms. TradingView scripts must be written in [Pine Script](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Introduction.html). Furthermore, the file structure used to save scripts from the Pine Editor is flat; it doesn't allow for sub-directories.